# Error when adding or deleting a tenant [thingsboard]

Tags: thingsboard

I get the following error when adding or deleting a tenant on thingsboard: "could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet"

Restarted all the services and DB.